# Is it possible to store date and time inside an Integer?

Tags: delphi, tdatetime

I've created a logger that parse big .txt archives and convert each line of the file to an TObject composed of:

`_date`: TDateTime;

`_ip`: Integer;

`_port`: Word;

`_bytes`: TBytes;

Example of line:

```
01/12/2017 18:01:59.999 192.168.1.64:50000 0100021DC8
date ip:port bytes
```

As these .txt files are big, the number of generated objects are also enormous and so is the memory usage. Hence, in order to reduce memory usage I wonder if it is possible to store the `_date` field as an Integer instead of a TDateTime.

Comment: No. You can **convert** a TDateTime to something that can be stored in an integer (using shifts), like a DosDateTime (see [`FileTimeToDosDateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724274(v=vs.85).aspx)), but you'll lose precision. It will be precise up to 2 seconds, at best. No milliseconds, no odd seconds. But you'll only gain 4 bytes per date/time combo anyway. Is that worth the trouble?

Comment: You might store deltas between records.

Comment: After parsing all the files my executable is consuming 400MB RAM, it would help a lot if I could cut that consumption in half. I didn't understand what you mean @Victoria

Comment: You'd have a log start, which would be a date time. And every record would have a time delta since the previous one (starting at 0 with the first record).

Comment: One possibility is Unix time stamps that hold number of seconds since the "Unix epoch" (1.1.1970) in an integer. Delphi has ready made conversion functions. You would lose the milliseconds you indicated. An alternative is to invent your own epoch e.g. today, and then you could also maintain the milliseconds for some time ahead into the future. Anyway, storing all those data in a binary form would already reduce memory usage a lot.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary for your application to load the *entire* log file in the first place? This is where typically, multiple log files are created, for example, one per day, or maximum file size, or maximum entries, etc. Even if that weren't the case, does your app really need to load the full file? I'd consider chunking it to only those portions which are actually relevant.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: the problem with using Unix timestamps is 1) the RTL uses `Int64` for them, which is just as big in size as `TDateTime` (8 bytes), and 2) if you truncate them to 32 bits, they will [overflow in 2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem), which is not that far away (software can easily be used for 20+ years).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh, I did not know about the RTL using Int64. Then I think it's plain wrong, not to use milliseconds resolution, which I recall being at least discussed as the future Unix Time Stamp structure (I don't recall seeing a final decission) . Anyway, truncating to 32 bits is an option despite its limited usage timeframe, OP will decide based on their requirements, but thanks for adding those details and limitations.

Comment: To fit a date/time into 32 bits, best to use an offset from an epoch, but you lose precision (ie, by using # of seconds from epoch and ignore milliseconds). On the other hand, if you can ignore milliseconds, you *can* bit-stuff a full date/time into 32 bits, if you represent the year as an offset from a starting year, as there would be only 6 bits for it (`2017` needs 11 bits). If you shorten one of the other fields, you can have more year bits (for instance, [DOS timestamps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724274.aspx) divide seconds in half to make room for 7 bits)

Comment: @Remy: as I said... DosDateTime. Gave the same link. <g>

Comment: ISTM that if you convert the text to binary, you already reduce the size considerably. Especially if the bytes part is large, the few bytes saved for the TDateTime won't gain you a lot. If, OTOH, the bytes part is limited to, say 8 or 16 bytes, you might better use a fixed size array. TBytes also has some overhead (8 bytes per TBytes, plus the memory manager data). I don't know your typical data, so it is hard to give better advice. But do as others say: don't load the entire log into memory. Scan it line by line or block by block.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis istm that OP is very likely storing the text as binary. However everything else you say is spot on assuming OP is compiling 32-bit. If 64-bit, there is +4 bytes for longer pointer to `TBytes` on heap and +4 bytes for increased size of internal `Length` of array. PS: Because OP is storing each line as an object there is already an additional pointer overhead for each object instance.

Comment: @noen In a nutshell, Rudy is pointing out that you're trying to scrape off a mere 4 bytes per object from a structure that uses a minimum of 27 bytes (assuming no empty byte arrays). _**Forget about** "cutting consumption in half"._ You're likely to be much better off taking a different approach/design to reduce memory consumption that doesn't involve trashing precision on date-times. (Note that it's difficult for us to make suggestions because of the X-Y problem. You haven't stated much about what led you to ask about storing `TDateTime` as `Integer` in the first place.)

Comment: @CraigYoung: Yes, I assumed he is storing the hex as binary. But if this can be done in, say, 8 or 16 bytes, I would get rid of the TBytes overhead and use a fixed size array (of bytes). And indeed, I meant that getting rid of 4 bytes per record won't greatly reduce his memory woes.He'd rather save elsewhere, e.g., if possible, on the byte array (which as at least 8 bytes overhead, if not more).

Comment: @CraigYoung: I actually missed the fact he is storing them as objects instead of records. That has an overhead too, indeed, in the time and memory domain. Many more ways to optimize than reducing the TDateTime.

Comment: Just to clarify that some of you suggested me to not load all the data just part of it. That is exactly what I am doing already. These loaded .txts are files filtered in a specific date range, like from day 01/12 to 03/12. Furthermore, I can't use static arrays because the length can vary a lot (from 1 byte to 500 bytes).

Comment: I just found that there is a design pattern for this exactly problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern